# How to replace a javascript file request with contents from another file in a FF addon?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm looking for some guidance on how to replace requests for a specific javascript file with another file that I'll package with the Firefox addon.

Comment: Do you mean that e.g. some HTML page would try to load http://somesite.com/somefile.js using a `<script>` tag, but your addon would intercept that request and serve another file (from the plugin) altogether?

Comment: I'm very interested in this. Would be great for being able to distribute the CSS/Javascript/Images portions of a web app so as to lighten the load on Users over poor/slow web connections (eg. Africa, Pacific Islands)

Comment: @Vlad you are correct, it's for ga.js specifically. I want to make an addon to disable GA.

Comment: @Damo I was thinking the same thing, could speed up library loading, etc..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [How can I implement a content converter in Firefox for all page elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079115/how-can-i-implement-a-content-converter-in-firefox-for-all-page-elements) (its scope is much wider than what you really need -- read on) on how to use [`registerFactory`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NsIComponentRegistrar/registerFactory) to register a surrogate [HTTP protocol handler](http://doxygen.db48x.net/mozilla-full/html/d9/d68/interfacensIHttpProtocolHandler-members.html), which can then instantiate channels with alternate (e.g. `file:///...`-type) URIs when `newChannel` is called with your particualr script's URI.

Comment: So replace newchannel in `var newchannel = this.savedHttpHandler.newChannel(locationURI);` when locationURI is a ga.js uri? and replace it to a channel for a local copy included with the extension?

Comment: Exactly.

Another option would have been to rewrite `<javascript>` nodes in the DOM, but I think that the protocol factory is simpler and more generic in this case.

Comment: Thanks this information is helping, I'll be trying it out soon.